# AESMode with ECB Encryption and Decryption in Golang without padding

Tags: go, encryption, aes, ecb

I want to do `AESMode with ECB Encryption and Decryption` in Golang.

Key: `2A07EEF4384E7CD9671E1ED5BCF60029`
Encrypted Sample Msg base64 Encoded: `g08cALdBhD8Q21d4pfjBKg==`
I'm not able to decrypt the message. Can anyone help me how can I do AESMODE.ECB enc/dec in Golang.

Currently I'm using
[github.com/andreburgaud/crypt2go/ecb](//pkg.go.dev/github.com/andreburgaud/crypt2go/ecb) lib

**Encrypt Code**

```
 func EncryptASEWithECB(pt, key []byte) string {
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    mode := ecb.NewECBEncrypter(block)
    ct := make([]byte, len(pt))
    mode.CryptBlocks(ct, pt)
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(ct)
}
```

**Decrypt Code**

```
func DecryptASEWithECB(ct, key []byte) string {
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    mode := ecb.NewECBDecrypter(block)
    pt := make([]byte, len(ct))
    mode.CryptBlocks(pt, ct)
    return string(pt)
}
```

I'm getting result Correct when I tried with this
**Test Case**

```
func TestEncryptWithECB(b *testing.T) {
    key := []byte("2A07EEF4384E7CD9671E1ED5BCF60029")
    plaintext := []byte("exampleplaintext")
    encrypted := utils.EncryptASEWithECB(plaintext,key)
    fmt.Printf("encrypted : %s\n", encrypted)

    //plaintext = []byte(encrypted)
    
    sDec,err:= base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(encrypted)
    fmt.Println(string(sDec),err)

    decrypted := utils.DecryptASEWithECB(sDec, key)
    fmt.Printf("decrypted : %s\n", decrypted)
}
```

**Problem**
The problem is I have to use AESMODE.ECB to fetch the value from below encrypted message
This key and Message is coming from 3rd party and they Said we have to use AESMODE.ECB without padding to decrypt this message.

```
Key: `2A07EEF4384E7CD9671E1ED5BCF60029`
Encrypted Sample Msg base64 Encoded: `g08cALdBhD8Q21d4pfjBKg==`
```

But I'm not able to do that.
Anyone help how can I do that ?

**Solution**
**Testing Func Updated**

```
key, err := hex.DecodeString("2A07EEF4384E7CD9671E1ED5BCF60029")

func TestEncWithECB(b *testing.T) {
    //key := 
    //plaintext = []byte(encrypted)
    key,_ := hex.DecodeString("2A07EEF4384E7CD9671E1ED5BCF60029") //encode key in bytes to string and keep as secret, put in a vault
    fmt.Printf("key to encrypt/decrypt : %s\n", key)
    
    sDec,err:= base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString("g08cALdBhD8Q21d4pfjBKg==")
    fmt.Println(string(sDec),err)

    decrypted := utils.DecryptASEWithECB(sDec, key)
    fmt.Printf("decrypted : %s\n", decrypted)
}
```

Comment: I didn't test anything but maybe the key is the **hex string** representation of the key, so you could check with a "hex string to byte array converter" and use the result as input for your decryption function :-)

Comment: The key must be [hex](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/) decoded: `key, err := hex.DecodeString("2A07EEF4384E7CD9671E1ED5BCF60029")`. The decryption is _testing go_.

Comment: Yes It worked thanks MichaelFehr and Topaco. 
Thanks a lot.
I will update post and post the solution with that.